# How to make re-usable tabs component with page routing (Navbar) with next Js, Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, tabs, navigation

I can't make a reusable nav bar component from tabs from MUI in next js.

So I am trying to use tabs from MUI as a navigation bar. I also want it to be re-usable, so using a const to populate it, and have it "route" to different pages when different tabs are selected.

Basically I want to do this with next js preferably reusable

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-tab-react-router-bovd0?file=/src/Books.js:0-118

I have only been able to make it with the reusable tabs but not with routing. Can anyone help? Is it maybe unnecessary to have the routing as well?

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide a [mre].